# The tag excerpt is not shown after editing a tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

When a tag is edited, the excerpt is not shown on the ["Thanks for your edit", or "tag info" page, page](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/protractor/info). The body of the tag is shown, which serves as a useful feedback (verification of a successful edit), but not the excerpt:

> [image: Thanks for tag edit page]

To prove that there *is* an excerpt, here is the tag being edited. The excerpt is clearly visible:

> [image: Tag edit page]

Should not the tag edit thanks page show the excerpt as well as the tag definition body?

Please note: The tag that I was editing was a newly created tag, that had not yet been approved, so would that explain it? I have not had chance to edit an "already approved" tag, to see if there is a difference. I will do so and post the screenshot to compare.

Update: The excerpt is not shown for both existing tags with pre-approved excerpts as well as new unapproved tags.

Comment: It was precisely the "double check your work" functionality that I felt was missing :-)